# Why is there no article "the" before "international law"?

Tags: definite-articles

Reading through wikipedia's page on [international law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_law), I noticed that there is never a definite article "*the*" before the phrase. It is a set of rules, norms, and standards generally recognised as binding between states, so it should be quite a definitive thing, right? So why is there no definite article?

Compare: *the* constitution, *the* second amendment, *the* Bill of Rights, [*the* Defense of Marriage Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_of_Marriage_Act), *the* Non-Proliferation Treaty.

Comment: Compare *global warming, nuclear proliferation, maritime law,...*

Comment: [The UN](https://www.un.org/en/global-issues/international-law-and-justice) actually uses the definite article _on occasion_.

Comment: It's a non-count noun in this context. But it's also just traditional.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Considering the plethora of _international law_ in that article and the one single example left misusing it, that's less "the UN" and more "a French intern who missed one of her typos".

Comment: @lly: or, that usage is eliding "body of" (which is still awkward, but becomes a style issue rather than a typo).

Comment: @minnmass I mean, I can parse it. It's still awkward to the point of seeming more like a French typo than a stylistic choice. They don't seem to have explained that choice, it doesn't seem to add to the sentence at all, and they don't seem to have gone back to it the other 20 or 30 times they mentioned the phrase...

Comment: @lly That particular use is by no means a typo or incorrect; in fact, it would be incorrect without the article. Every other instance of _international law_ on the page refers to the concept in general and therefore does not have an article, but this one is directly referring to the specific body of international law mentioned in the previous sentence, and as such, the article is non-negotiable. Leaving it out would change the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: "standards *generally recognised* as binding between states [...] and operates largely through *consent*" - there's nothing definitive about that whatsoever.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Absolutely not. As repeatedly stated and explained at length elsewhere up and down this post, international law doesn't take a direct article. It was a mistake there and not in any sense a separate, special, or specific idea, except in mistranslation.

Comment: @lly No. You are quite simply incorrect. As any other comparable phrase, it can take a definite article in the right contexts, and in such contexts, leaving out the article is ungrammatical. “The international law the US follows is not the same international law as the one Russia follows” is perfectly grammatical, whereas “*International law the US follows is not same international law as (the?) one Russia follows” is **completely and utterly ungrammatical**. The fact that international law as a concept does not take an article does not mean that it never can. No such rule exists in English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Your sentence is completely correct. Your general reasoning in this last comment is completely correct. None of it applies to the quoted passage in the UN statement. "The international law the US follows" would be a separate, special, or specific idea. There's no such restrictive clause or context prompting that definite article and it was utterly mistaken.

Comment: @lly The passage in question reads, “Among the greatest achievements of the United Nations is the development of a body of international law, which is […]. The international law is enshrined in conventions, treaties and standards”. It is clear to me that the second sentence refers back to the first; it could be rephrased to “… a body of international law, which is […], and which is enshrined in conventions…”, or “… a body of international law, which is […]. This international law…”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _This_ [thing I just talked about]  works. _The_ [thing] _which..._ works. _The International Law_ with no restrictive clause following it and only in the context of general international law is different from both of those other structures and remains mistaken.

Comment: @lly I will simply say that I agree that ‘the international law’ only in the context of general international law is incorrect, but that the instance in question here is not only in the context of general international law. The context is precisely what makes it _not_ incorrect, but perfectly valid. The article could have been omitted, but then it would be a different statement, one about international law in general. That’ll be my final word on this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

International law isn't one single thing as your examples. It is a body of law comprising *international treaties, customary international law, general legal principles and judicial decisions and the teachings of prominent legal scholars*, as explained by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_law#Sources_of_international_law).

It is a collection of resources, so "the international law" is incorrect.

Comment: Further to this: there is vanishingly little disagreement about what the text of, say, the Constitution is (much less the Defense of Marriage Act). International Law isn't just a body of texts and traditions, its one whose borders are fuzzy (eg., there could be reasonable arguments about whether a specific scholar's work - or even a specific work of a given scholar - should be considered as part of the body of International Law).

Comment: I'm not sure there is a general principle of English grammar saying that you can't use a definite article in front of a `collection of resources`. Compare `the world's forests`, `the internet`, `the solar system`. Can you define `collection of resources` in a way that addresses these edge cases?

Comment: @Max in your example 'the' applies to 'world' which is (hopefully) one world: the world.

Answer (score 7):

*International law* doesn't specify a definite law, bill, treaty, or code. Rather it is more like a general field or area governed by many laws, bills, treaties, norms, conventions, and practices. Such a general area usually doesn't take a definite article. Compare these other examples of areas of *law* from [LSAC](https://www.lsac.org/discover-law/types-law-programs/fields-law), all typically lacking an article:

- animal law
- corporate law
- criminal law
- education law
- employment law
- family law
- health law
- immigration law
- intellectual policy law
- international law
- juvenile law
- labor law
- municipal law
- real estate law
- securities law
- sports law
- tax law

This use of *law* is in the same vein as other fields, which commonly use adjective-noun or noun-noun phrasing without an article: particle physics, evolutionary biology, abstract mathematics, cognitive science, sports history, English literature, secondary education.

The definite article would be used for a definite source of law, such as *the Vienna Convention on the Law of Treaties* ([source](https://brill.com/display/title/15148)) or *the Par in parem non habet imperium principle* ([source](https://file:///C:/Users/jwhoward/Downloads/_book_edcoll_9789004296060_B9789004296060-s002-preview.pdf)). It also might be used if one specified a more specific area of focus within international law, as the *[Stockton Center for International Law](https://usnwc.edu/Research-and-Wargaming/Research-Centers/Stockton-Center-for-International-Law)* does when mentioning "the international law of conflict in the airspace, outer space, and cyberspace."

Answer (score 6):

If your intention is to refer to a subject area, or a set of similar items to state it in very broad terms, and to do so by its name, then you don't use the definite article; and if you want to refer to a particular example or instance of the subject or set, then you do use the definite article:

> I have a friend who is an expert on Abstract Art.
>
> I'm not a fan of the <sup>no</sup> abstract art.
>
> The <sup>yes</sup> abstract art hanging in that museum attracts visitors from all over the world.

Consider the noun phrase **Italian cooking**.  You wouldn't feel as though **the** was needed there, would you? And that's because Italian cooking is the name for the cuisine(s) of Italy.

> I like the Italian cooking...  <sup>not idiomatic</sup>

The adjective **Italian** is a "determiner", IMO, in this case a proper adjective (and by "proper" I mean *name-related*) in the proper noun phrase, which specifies the kind of cooking.  Greek sculpture, Japanese poetry, Kansas BBQ. Abstract Art.

We don't typically use a definite article in tandem with a proper adjective, unless we're creating a subset such as by referring to a particular example or group of examples of the thing:

> *The* Italian cooking *I've tried* has given me indigestion.

You're referring there not to Italian cooking as a whole, as a cuisine, but to actual individual dishes that were examples of it.

In your example, "law" is like "cooking", something encompassing a number of categories: maritime law, elder law, divorce law, criminal law, state law, federal law, and so forth.  "International"  specifies the particular sort of law.

P.S. And **International Law** can be the *name* for the body of law as a subject for study, a discipline, or as the category of law that governs certain situations. Consider another example. Although **maritime** can be a simple adjective meaning "connected with the sea, bordering the sea, relating to the sea", when it becomes part of the *name* for the body of law governing the merchant marine, ocean commerce, flotsam and jetsam, etc etc, **Maritime Law**, it becomes a proper adjective. Which is to say, native speakers treat as such.

Comment: Broadly speaking the right idea but it'd be better if the examples leading into your point were focused so much on proper adjectives when _international_ isn't one.

Comment: @Ily In *titular* constructions the adjective **International** does function like a proper adjective; the same would be true of the adjective **elder** in *Elder Law*.

Comment: It functions like a proper adjective in the sense that it's an adjective that achieves a delimiting purpose. Neither of those are actually proper adjectives, though. Italian food capitalizes Italian and not food. The Elder Law is either a specific law or both words are lower-case because elder isn't a proper adjective the way Italian is.

Comment: As stated, that whole part of the answer is mistaken and misfocused despite the actual answer bit still being mostly correct. It'd be improved by removing it and using apter examples.

Comment: But we wouldn't write **The Elder Law** but **Elder Law**, It is the *name* for the body of law, and is in that sense a "proper adjective".

Comment: I don’t really see the purpose of this discussion on proper adjectives – it doesn’t change anything whether the adjective is proper or not. You could substitute _vegan cooking_ or _macrobiotic cooking_ instead of _Italian cooking_ and the determiner usage would still be the same.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  I don't approach it in terms of purpose but in terms of speaker behavior.  When the adjective + noun phrase is being used to *name* something collective  or generic (e.g. cuisine, law, art), the adjective becomes "proper" and no article is used.

Comment: It is an effect of *naming* that the adjective becomes "elevated" to proper status.

Comment: To be clear, I was talking about the discussion in the comments, not in the answer. Perhaps an additional example using a non-proper adjective would improve the answer, but since the properness of the adjective doesn’t really make a difference to begin with, the following four comments don’t really seem relevant to me. (Incidentally, something that _is_ misleading in the answer is calling _Italian_ a ‘determiner’. That term has a specific meaning in grammar, and while _the_ is a determiner, adjectives are not. I’d change it to something like ‘specifier’ instead to avoid ambiguity.)

Comment: “It is an effect of naming that the adjective becomes "elevated" to proper status” — No. A proper adjective is an adjective derived from a proper noun (or proper name); nothing more, nothing less. Using an adjective in a specific way doesn’t change the properness of the adjective.

Comment: When you say "proper adjective", do you mean "adjective as opposed to a noun used attributively" or "adjective derived from a proper noun", because those are two very different things.

Comment: And it's not an issue of the adjective being used as a determiner. "Law", and "cooking", "sculpture", "poetry"  and "BBQ", for that matter, is simply a mass noun that is indefinite in this context, which demands the zero article. There is no determiner

Comment: This answer suggests that if I wanted to order a salad, I would say, `I will have the salad`, but if I wanted to order a large salad, I would say `I will have large salad`.

Comment: I am using "proper" to mean "name-related". This kind of descriptor+noun phrase is a *name* for a set or collection of related items: maritime law, Italian cooking, Greek sculpture, elder law. And regardless of whether the descriptor is an adjective (maritime) or a noun (elder), the phrase is never preceded by the definite article when the set is being referred to *qua* set. The article is used with the descriptor+noun only when referring to a *subset* or an *instance* of the class, and then the descriptor is no longer "proper" (name-related) but simply a descriptor.

Comment: @Max: what is set-related about "large salad"?

Comment: You forgot to @ me,  and you should definitely put that explanation of "proper" into your answer, or else use a different word

Comment: @NoName: Ah, sorry. I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: @Tim Suppose the menu is `fries; salad; sandwich` and each item comes in sizes `small; medium; large`. In this context, `salad` is a set of three possible orders, namely `small salad`, `medium salad`, and `large salad`. Note the parallel with `politics; policy; law` and (say) `domestic; maritime; international`.

Comment: @Max:  But the essential element of my answer is *naming*.  Large salad is not a name like Cobb salad.   You could call an article in a cooking blog "Cobb Salad" but not "Large salad".

Answer (score 1):

[Weather Vane already hit the main point](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/610015/171986) but just to make it explicit:

> Compare: the constitution, the second amendment, the Bill of Rights, the Defense of Marriage Act, the Non-Proliferation Treaty.

If those were properly used (which in the implicit American context would *also* require capitalizing to the Constitution and the Second Amendment), every one of those is referring to the specific proper name of a specific law or group of laws. They're only unusual in that they have a definite article at all, which English generally uses for names that are specific instances of a common noun: the fifty states of the United States, the four constituent countries of the United Kingdom, etc. The Second Amendment of the Constitution is actually kinda special in that Americans discuss those amendments *a lot* so what was originally rather descriptive becomes a proper name through repetitive specific use.

The International Law, if it existed, would be a single specific law or set of laws that people specifically reference. That *can* happen: It's pretty standard in English to talk about *the* Law of the Sea. That's because—outside of China getting its footing on being a Great Power again—there's a few centuries of pretty broad agreement on important and specific terms there, at least in peacetime and on some points even during war.

By contrast, actual international law is just a hodgepodge of treaties, agreements, norms, assumptions, good wishes, &c. with very few enforcement mechanisms *and* English speakers usually think about it and talk about it in those terms. This is different from (e.g.) French that uses its definite article much more liberally *and* French speakers who generally feel that stronger international institutions help protect them and improve life overall versus (e.g.) Americans who widely consider their Constitution a nearly divinely inspired document trumping any possible horsetrading they may sometimes be forced into with more benighted countries.